# jQuery call REST API not working in Docker/Kubernetes

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

This is a Java Spring boot REST API application, using an index.html to present the UI web page to user.
When the index.html is displayed, it would trigger the logic from the Javascript/jQuery to make a REST api call(coded as below) to the backend service in the Java controller class to get 2 random generated numbers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/multiplications/random"
```

The program is working fine when run it as a Spring Boot app in Eclipse!

However, it's not working after I used the .jar file to build a Docker image file then deployed it using Kubernetes/minikube(I'm new to Docker/Kubernetes).

here's the dockfile to build the image file using the .jar:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

ADD target/social-multiplication-v3-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Here's the deployment.yaml file:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: multiplicationservice
spec:
  selector: 
      app: multiplication
  ports:
     - protocol: "TCP"
       port:  80
       targetPort:  8080
       nodePort:  30001
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mdeploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: multiplication
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: multiplication
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: multiplication
        image: huxianjun/multiplication
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and the IP address of the host where the application being deployed in Kubernetes:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.99.101
```

At the end, I can get to the index.html page from browser by folllowing URL:

```
http://192.168.99.101:30001/
```

The page is being displayed as expected - What NOT working is, the following REST api call didn't occur thus the 2 numbers not returned from the call and displayed on the page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/multiplications/random"
```

My guess is, is it caused by the 'localhost' & the port'8080' not aligned with those port# defined in the deployment.yaml file? or even something conflict to the 'EXPOSE 8080' in the docfile?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you are calling the `$.ajax` command from your browser which is in your host machine, hence, those API calls will be sent from your local machine but not within your docker container.

To solve the problem, you can update the URL to be using `http://192.168.99.101:30001/` like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.99.101:30001/multiplications/random"
```

Comment: You are right that I simply verified by typing 'http://192.168.99.101:30001/multiplications/random' in the browser,and got the response as expected:
{"factorA":89,"factorB":52}

However, after I changed it in calling $.ajax, the response was not passed back to the index.html and displayed on the page. Below is the codes:

the codes in index.html:
```
        <span class="multiplication-a"></span> x <span class="multiplication-b"></span> 
```

Comment: and the codes in the JS program:
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.99.101:30001/multiplications/random"
    }).then(function(data) {
        $('.multiplication-a').empty().append(data.factorA);
        $('.multiplication-b').empty().append(data.factorB);

Comment: My bad - the reason it didn't work after I changed the JS codes is I missed to push the updated image file to Docker repository. Now everying works well after the push!

Comment: That’s great, I am glad that the answer solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try run `sudo lsof -i :8080`, if you use **linux**. It'll show all your available ports. If you don't see 8080 port, your application's port aren't available and visible for your localhost. That's because Docker containers are "closed/isolated" for all external processes and files. Moreover, `EXPOSE 8080` instruction in Dockerfile is not enough.
Try `docker run -p 8080:8080 YOUR_CREATED_IMAGE_NAME`. It will build redirection from *docker container* **localhost:8080** to Your **localhost:8080**

Comment: I'm not using linux...I understand what you meant to run 'docker run -p 8080:8080'.
then further question:
1.when call a REST api service, the UI program(the JS pgm in my case) specify a port
2.when build an image file, the docfile specify a port# by 'EXPOSE 8080' (I feel this seems not very necessary since subsequently kubernetes will also specify the ports)
3.when deploy the application using kubernetes, the deployment.yaml specify the port# again
I'm new to this, could you advise what topic I should fuether study to understand how to reconcile all the above?

Comment: 1. I did not understand the question)
2. `'EXPOSE 8080'` in Dockerfile is just like a *hint* for deploying and for person, who will deploy it. it doesn't make connection or redirection with your localhost ports and ports on containers.
3. i didn't work with `Kubernetes`, sorry. i use `docker-compose`

Comment: It's ok...now I realized it's all related to Docker/Kubernetes networking, which I'm trying to understand now